# android mapView

Tags: android, dictionary

I can generate a fingerpaint eith this command 
C:\Documents and Settings\pc3>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
 "D:\brijesh_android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android.
When it execute than error willbe generate like Access is denied.

Comment: you are using the exact above command..

Comment: What a horrible title/subject election...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give password but probably you have not set password to the Debug key

so do not need to write password if you have not set in DEBUG KEY

just write

```
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass -keypass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\<path-to-jdk-dir>\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\brijesh_android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

keytool.exe exists in jre6\bin, Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed the method of obtainig map keys, previously it was using MD5 fingerprint 
Now you can follow the link to integrate the map

[Integrating google maps in android applicaiton](http://androidgeekworks.blogspot.com/2013/07/integrating-google-maps-in-android.html)